# Is it possible to create a bitmap, add it to canvas and draw it using view.draw?

Tags: java, android

For example ..

```
        Bitmap myPic = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        Bitmap newPic = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(myPic, 50, 50, true);
        Canvas myCanv = new Canvas(newPic);
        View myView = (View)findViewById(R.id.view1);
        myView.draw(myCanv);
```

is something like the above feasible?

Comment: Why do you need the canvas? You could just set the Bitmap as myView's image.

Comment: please explain what you want to achieve doing this?

Comment: Android Developer, I'm just learning how drawing in android works, so I'm playing around with canvas and drawing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really shouldn't do it like that. My recommendation is to do it like this

```
Bitmap myPic = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
myPic = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(myPic,50,50, true);
BitmapDrawable draw = new BitmapDrawable(this.getResources(), myPic);
View myView = (View) findViewById (R.id.view1);
myView.setBackground(draw);
```

This way you pass your `View` a drawable as a background.
If you really want to set a `Bitmap` as your source then you should make an `ImageView`

Comment: It should be added that if he really wants to draw on canvas as said in his comment, subclassing the view, overriding onDraw and drawing there with canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap) is THE approach.